# Form radio/checkbox inputs wont select when using preventDefault()

Tags: jquery, checkbox, input, toggle

I am adding a class of .selected to the surrounding div of an input[type="checkbox] when it is clicked like this:

```
<label class="checkbox-button">
    <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" id="">
    <div class="checkbox-button-span">
        <span class="checkbox-button-circle"></span>
        <span class="checkbox-button-label">Yes</span>
    </div>
</label>

<script>
$('.checkbox-button').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  e.preventDefault();
});</script>
```

The function is adding the class to the surrounding div as expected, however when using preventDefault - it no longer initiates a click on the input. Alternatively, if I remove preventDefault - toggleClass no longer initiates.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the click event, try using the change event of the checkbox itself to toggle the class. This will cause the code to run whether the value changes because of clicking on the label or the checkbox directly.

```
$('.checkbox-button :checkbox').on('change', function (e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
});
```